# Add an element at the beginning of a JSON using JSON_MODIFY

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to build a JSON from the following table

```
 name | flag 
------+------
 foo  | fail 
 bar  | pass
```

using the query,

```
DECLARE @JSONDATA nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT [name], [flag]
FROM test
FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('students'))
SET @JSONDATA = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONDATA, '$.class','10')
```

The generated JSON here is

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "flag": "fail"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "flag": "pass"
    }
  ],
  "class": "10"
}
```

I need to the `class` element at the very first node of the JSON. Is there any way, using `JSON_MODIFY` ?

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/036f9/1/0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a loss forcing a sequence via modify.

Perhaps an alternative

```
Select class=10
      ,students =  (SELECT [name], [flag] FROM test FOR JSON AUTO)
  For JSON path, without_array_wrapper
```

**Returns**

```
{
    "class": 10,
    "students": [{
        "name": "foo",
        "flag": "fail"
    }, {
        "name": "bar",
        "flag": "pass"
    }]
}
```

**EDIT-** Updated SELECT as suggested by GSerg

Comment: @an33sh. Happy to help.